# Using a mixin/function to poplulate @import paths in Stylus

Tags: import, mixins, stylus

I was hoping to be able to do something like the following in Stylus:

```
variables (spec)
  "../" + spec + "/css/variables.styl"

@import variables(button);
@import variables(form);
..
```

There is reasoning for the file structure I am just trying to make it easier to manage the repetition in this file rather than having to write:

```
@import "../button/css/variables.styl"
@import "../form/css/variables.styl"
..
```

But when I try the Stylus compiler errors with "@import string expected"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you just need to remove the space before `()`, otherwise the declaration is parsed as a selector:

```
variables(spec)
  "../" + spec + "/css/variables.styl"

@import variables(button);
@import variables(form);
```